# Google text to speech - SSML breaks missing from mp3 output

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Am experiencing an issue with SSML tags being 'dropped' when converting base-64 output from Google Text to Speech to an MP3 file.

Platform is OSX 10.12.6.

My syntax seems to be fine and tests OK with other services but, when I convert it through terminal it drops all my SSML.

Have been messing around trying different things for the last 8 hours!

My call to the API is:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'ssml':'<speak>
First sentence<break time="3s"/>
Second sentence <break time="300ms"/><say-as interpret-as="date" format="yyyy" detail="1">1919</say-as><break time="2s"/>
Third sentence <say-as interpret-as="characters">send</say-as> <break time="300ms"/><say-as interpret-as="date" format="yyyy" detail="1">2016</say-as><break time="2s"/>
Fourth sentence <say-as interpret-as="cardinal">10456</say-as> <break time="300ms"/><say-as interpret-as="date" format="yyyy" detail="1">2017</say-as><break time="2s"/>
Fifth sentence <say-as interpret-as="unit">10 foot</say-as> <break time="300ms"/><say-as interpret-as="time" format="hms12">3:30am</say-as><break time="2s"/>
</speak>'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Wavenet-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3',
      'pitch': '0',
      'speakingRate': '0.90'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" > complex-test.txt
```

And then the output is converted to MP3 using:

```
sed 's|audioContent| |' < complex-test.txt > tmp-output.txt && \
tr -d '\n ":{}' < tmp-output.txt > tmp-output-2.txt && \
base64 tmp-output-2.txt --decode > complex-test.mp3 && \
rm tmp-output*.txt
```

The output is just one rapid fire spoken track with no breaks and none of the SSML tags work.

Any fresh ideas appreciated!

Many thanks.